Как выполнить bash-скрипт после выполнения NPM-скрипта?
Есть npm-скрипт, который запускает сборку сайта:
npm run buildSingle --argv "dir/index.html"


После выполнения этого скрипта нужно автоматически выполнять bash-скрипт.
Как это можно сделать, если это возможно?

Так и в чём проблема запустить баш-скрипт? npm run buildSingle ... && run-my-bash-script

@AlexeyTen Оформите этот комментарий в ответ, всё верно же
